# How do you change colour scheme between *panes* inside iTerm2 + oh-my-zsh?

Tags: iterm, zsh

I have seen a lot of solutions that allow changing of tab colour upon remote accessing into a server (see for example: https://gist.github.com/wadey/1140259 and many more).

What I want is to change the colour of the *split pane*. The workflow that I normally follow is:

1. Open iTerm2
2. Split panes and remote the right half into another server
3. While keeping the left half on my local machine

I don't have quite the background of bash/zsh, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to install the "Shell Integration" tools, using this menu in iTerm:

[image: iTerm2 Menu]

Once you've done that you will have access to several iTerm-specific tools, including `it2setcolor` which lets you easily change the colors.

For example, I use this as part of my `ssh` alias for connecting to a remote server:

```
it2setcolor preset 'Solarized Light'
```

so whenever I `ssh` somewhere, iTerm automatically changes the 'Theme' to 'Solarized Light'.

(Run `it2setcolor` with no args to get a usage summary.)